# Are sql dumps moved into docker container `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` encrypted?

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm dumping a database into a sql dump:

```
docker exec mysql sh -c 'exec mysqldump --all-databases -uroot -ppassword' > all-databases.sql
```

Then I'm using a Dockerfile to build a mysql image and run as a container:

```
FROM mysql:5.6.41

# needed for intialization
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=whateverPassword

ADD all-databases.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

EXPOSE 3306
```

When I run the container if I exec into the container, can I access the all-databases.sql file and see the contents of my database in plaintext in the docker image?

Currently if I look into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` it says all-databases.sql but I don't know where that file is stored/if it's encrypted.

Comment: have you checked the contents of  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/all-databases.sql file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `docker exec` into the container, the file will be unencrypted.  (It's just a text file and you can look at it with `more` on most image bases.)

However, if you can run any Docker command at all, then generally it's trivial to get unrestricted root access on the system.  (Consider using `docker run -v /etc:/host-etc` to add yourself to `/etc/sudoers` or to allow root logins with no password.)

Also remember that anyone who has the image can `docker run` it and see the file there, if that matters to your security concerns.  If you're looking for a single file with root access on the system anyways, you can find it without too much effort in `/var/lib/docker`.  They can also easily run `docker history` to see the database root password you've set.